# How to get value from array XML

Tags: php, xml, arrays, facebook-graph-api, xmpp

I want to develop chat with facebook by jaxl.v3.
This is my code

```
    `$client->add_cb('on_chat_message', function($stanza) {

                 global $client;
                 // echo back incoming message stanza 
                 $stanza->to = $stanza->from;
                 $stanza->from = $client->full_jid->to_string();
                 print_r($stanza);
                 sendMessage($client); 
      });`
```

This is my result that I print `print_r($stanza)` :

[image: image of my PrtScn]

What's I ask now:

- if I want to get  `[text]=>hi` value. how should I write? I am try my best a long time ago but I am still can't get value `Hi` from this array . pleases help me to solve it. Thanks 
  I am looking to see your reply soon.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
foreach($stanza->childrens as $child) {
   echo $child->text, '<br>';
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @silkfire. It's work. You're intelligent that just see it a few times you can do it in correct one